# What fuse can I use to replace a Hitachi FN00373

Tags: fuses

I'm trying to replace a blown fuse from my stereo system. 
The fuse has the following markings on one end: 125V 5A
and the following on the other: 51MS, an H with a circle around it (I'm assuming this means Hitachi), and some other symbols including the Underwriter Lab logo, an "SA" logo and an inverted triangle with a "T" inside (drawing below) and a line just above the T. It's 5mm x 20mm

[image: T Marking]

The fuse has a wire, then a small blob of metal, then another wire (which, to my untrained eye seems a bit thicker).

I think this is an M Spot Fuse, as described by @Harry Weston in this answer: [Slow Blow vs Fast Acting Fuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/slow-blow-vs-fast-acting-fuse)

As far as I can tell, this is a  Hitachi FN00373. Unfortunately this is a really rare fuse. I should also mention this stereo system is about 10-15 years old.

Is it possible/advisable to use a different fuse in its place (I'm not sure I can even get the Hitachi fuse anymore). Or, is it possible/advisable to use a slightly different fuse (e.g. one that isn't "M Spot" or has a slightly different voltage/current rating)? If you can recommend one, that would be ideal!

Comment: What size is it?  Common North American fuses are 1/4" dia 1 1/4" long, while metric fuses are 5 x 20 mm (or so).

Comment: Thanks for asking. It's 5x20mm, I just updated the question as well.

Comment: There's one question you haven't thought to ask, which could make the whole concept of replacing the fuse null and void: *why did the fuse blow in the first place?*

Comment: That's an excellent question, however I haven't touched this system in over half a decade. If I recall, I had been messing around using the system on different speakers, or with splicing the wires to make them longer. I think that's when it started. Anyway I just picked it up recently trying to figure out if I could fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that "51MS" is an entire family of fuses, all with the same basic characteristics but different current and voltage ratings. Assuming you can't find another "51MS-050L" from another manufacturer to replace it, you should be able to get away with any leadless, 5.2mm×20mm, medium slow-blow fuse rated for 5A and at least 125V.

[Source 1](http://www.epanorama.net/sff/Video/Products/Hitachi%20DP23-DP23G-DP24%20Projection%20TV%20Service%20Manual.pdf)

[Source 2](http://dblectro.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/1819-fr.pdf)

[Source 3](https://www.google.com/search?q=51ms+fuse)

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Can you comment on the form factor? Having that wire->metal blob->wire format? Can I do with a fuse that doesn't have that? Also  if you can share any links off hand that would be a huge help

Comment: I'd have to see a picture of that to understand what you mean.

Comment: There's a picture in the first question of the other answer I linked to.

Comment: The other answer called it an MSpot fuse

Comment: Looks just like the ones in the datasheet.

Comment: The first link is a TV repair manual and the last one is to google. The second link looks like exactly what I'm looking for but where do I get it?

Comment: The first link shows the internal Hitachi part number, and the third shows that it's a standard family.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46766/discussion-between-simapro-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Answer (score 0):

[image: 125V 5A quick blow (51MS) Radio Shack]

125V 5A 51 millisecond, available at Radio Shack, some auto stores, walmart etc. Was this soldered in, or is it just a glass fuse? Also, take a meter to it and verify that it is blown. It may be something internal.

Comment: I'm not convinced the ms stands for millisecond, because then I would have expected "ms" not "MS". Also I think there's some subtlety here with fast vs slow and the form factor (m spot vs f type)