# What is the name of a fuse with a half spring?

Tags: fuses

I have an Atari 400/800 Power Supply that the fuse blew. I've pulled the fuse out, it's a 5A/250VAC fuse, but I've been unable to find a direct replacement, as I don't know the exact name for this fuse type.  It appears to be a slow blow, but with a half spring.  I plan on modifying the supply and adding a fuse holder instead of direct soldering in a replacement.

There is another thread that mentions this type, but I don't have enough reputation to comment and ask a follow up, so I've made this question here.
Harry mentions this fuse type as the second type in his post here:
[Slow Blow vs Fast Acting Fuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/slow-blow-vs-fast-acting-fuse)

[image: Fuse from Atari 400/800 Power Supply]

Comment: I agree, it looks like a slow blow fuse.  Probably safe to replace with another 5A 250VAC slow blow fuse, but why it blew in the first place may need to be investigated.

Comment: Yeah, I investigated and I believe I found the cause. The Atari 400 has an RF wire that is wrapped around a ferrite choke inside the case.  However, the wire was attached to the case with a plastic clip and a 3M style adhesive pad, but the pad after 35yrs lost all it's stick, and the ferrite choke was loose.  In the case, it's just under the circuit board where the power enters, and I believe it was shorting a few pins.

Comment: Looks like a whole spring to me.

Comment: Doesnt look like anything to me