# What is the difference between "Slow Blow" and "Time Delay" fuse?

Tags: fuses

I'm wondering if there is any difference between "Slow Blow" and "Time Delay" fuse or those are just different terms.

There are many answares for [Slow Blow vs Fast Acting Fuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/slow-blow-vs-fast-acting-fuse) but are offtopic for this and unclear for this question.

Comment: I would look for datasheets and compare them.

Answer (score 4):

Just different names for the same thing. A slow-blow fuse is one that is resistant to nuisance opening often caused by inrush currents or current pulses.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion started when a popular brand of time delay fuses were labeled as "Slo-Blo" (which I think is a Trade/Model Name)?  Kind of like calling every brand of cola a "Coke".  Anyone know the history?